# HTML/CSS to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have the html and css for a site that I designed and am thinking about hiring a WP dev to put it all together.

2 Questions:

1).Would a dev be able to "transfer" the html/css into a wordpress site OR would they essentially have to start all over and "visually" build the front end from scratch based on what they see? It's my understanding that they would have to start over because wp does not accept html. I would prefer that the dev actually USE my html/css because I've spent so much time on it.

2). Are sites like Elance.com a good idea to build using WP?

Thank you again everyone! You guys are amazing here!
Brian

Answer (score 3):

1) They can use your html/css as a base to build the WP templates. Your code would be useful to them. They most likely won't be able to directly copy the files over, but they can open the files and copy/paste the parts to the appropriate WP PHP templates.

Short answer: yes, they would be able to "transfer" your code to WordPress

2) Building a data-heavy site like Elance would, in my opinion, be much easier with a web application framework like Ruby on Rails: http://rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Thank you for reply. Would small subtle positioning aspects be lost in the transfer? I just hate going back and forth saying "move this 5 pixels here, move that 3 pixles there...etc."

Comment: The dev has the ability to make sure your css settings are the final ones that appear on the screen. 
For a default Wordpress site, there are some default style settings that may overwrite or be mixed in with your set styles, so it's up to the dev to figure this out and make sure your settings are working as intended.

Comment: I've expanded my answer for #2

Comment: Tranquilize,My plan is to hire a WP dev for a very lite V1 of my idea to test the waters. Once I start making money from the site, I plan to put all money back into the site and hire another WP dev to add a few more features and then keep iterating like this. . My question is about being cost effective. It was my impression that repeatedly hiring a WP dev was more cost effective than doing this via traditional means (RoR, php, .NET...etc). Am I wrong? Also is it harder for a traditional dev (RoR, PHP, .NET) to pickup where another dev left off? More so than in WP?

Comment: I've very little experience with Wordpress outside of presentation or shopping catalog websites, as I feel Wordpress is a tool best suited to create those kind of sites (a site with many static pages and light data handling). I honestly think that it would be a better long term investment for you if you build your product on a

Comment: thanks tranquilize, I'm trying to do my research so any info is very helpful.

Comment: web application framework from scratch suited to your needs, so you can avoid the unnecessary parts of Wordpress that don't apply to your idea. 

I can't answer for every "traditional" or WP developer, but I believe it's easier to pick up other server code rather than WP/PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above answer, most of your HTML and CSS is used in exact same way in WP. All that is missing is some  to make it work and dynamic. However to build a site like Elance.com I wouldn't use a WP framework but rather build an actual service from scratch.

- PHP, ASP.NET, Python, Ruby on Rails
- Oracle, MySQL, SQL

It is up to you what you will decide to use what type of features will you decide to have on the website. You can build a simple job posting website with only PHP and MySQL and probably have it done in a week.

However if you decide to go a more professional rout and have some extra features and so on I would recommend building from scratch and not use plugins and crap to complete the project.

I wish this helps you, best of luck with your project

Comment: Ljubisa,My plan is to hire a WP dev for a very lite V1 of my idea to test the waters. Once I start making money from the site, I plan to put all money back into the site and hire another WP dev to add a few more features and then keep iterating like this. . My question is about being cost effective. It was my impression that repeatedly hiring a WP dev was more cost effective than doing this via traditional means (RoR, php, .NET...etc). Am I wrong? Also is it harder for a traditional dev (RoR, PHP, .NET) to pickup where another dev left off? More so than in WP?

Comment: It all depends on the quality of work your initial develop is doing, also it depends on how well he documents the code and how robust it is. Also keep in mind it is not easy to make money online, you need some capital to advertise so people actually know about you and to start using you. I would suggest before doing any programming or development to make a very good business plan and get someone to look it over. If you are not familiar with writing a business case you may just write it as a draft and get someone to help you complete the BC from your initial paper. Best of luck!